# Retrieve facebook messages with php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is it possible to access user's all facebook messages using facebook php sdk or graph api. I have a web application and I want my users to send and read facebook mesdages on my app.

Comment: Yes. You just need the user to accept extended permissions for your app.

Comment: I know it.. But I can't find any tutorial. Message object represents a single message. How can I get messages as an array, json or xml?

Comment: use the FB SDK : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Comment: Using Graph API requests. PHP or through JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. 
It is under the /user_id?fields=inbox

You will need read_mailbox (extended permissions) permission too.

Comment: how to assign permission to read_mailbox of my facebook app ?

Comment: @iqbalmalik you don’t, because that doesn’t exist any more.